# How can I have a variable that all model can access in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want all record in a user request have the same date_created (even milisecond). I intend to set a variable in CI_Model, and when it's loaded, all other Model can access it.

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this an actual variable or is it a constant?

Comment: This is an actual variable. It is initiated when a user request execute. And different for all of user requests. Literally, It's the created time of that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a global variable, you need to add a variable in  application/config/constants.php.

See steps :

1. Create your own file in application/libraries in which class
   constructor contains an array as an argument. Now create a new file
   in /application/config with same name as given in
   application/libraries and declare your global variables in it. Now
   to use these variables, autoload the newly created library.
2. Create your own file in application/core and declare the global
   variables in it. Than in controller you need to extend your file
   name instead of CI_Controller.
3. If the Global Variables are true constants, just add them in
   application/config/constants.php file and name them in all uppercase
   like the others are defined.
4. If you want to set application constants create new config file and
   add the variables. Now load it as $this->config->load(‘filename’);
   And access those variables as

$this->config->date_created(‘variable_name’);

Now you can use this function in every model.
Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Can you give me the document of step 1? I don't understand how it's work?

Comment: Please consider this link from codeignitor. https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html